# Induction in Lee's proof of Darboux theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

In Lee's *Introduction to Smooth manifolds* (earlier version), he proves the  Darboux theorem using

> **Lemma.** Let $(M, \omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, and let $(U;x_1, \ldots , x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ an open chart. Then $(x_1, \ldots , x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ are Darboux coordinates if and only if $$\{ x_i, x_j \}  = \{ y_i, y_j \} =0 \qquad , \qquad \{ x_i, y_j \}= - \delta_{ij} $$
>   **Lemma.** Let $M$ be a manifold and $X_1 , \ldots , X_r$ linearly independent vector fields. Then there exist coordinates $(u_1, \ldots, u_n)$ such that $X_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial u_i}$ if and only if $[X_i, X_j]=0$.

He uses induction on $k=0, \ldots , n$, and claim "for $k=0$ there is nothing to say", and start proving the general case. But I don't feel really comfortable with that, since $k=0$ is literally nothing.

So I would like to see at least the case $k=1$. But my problem arises when I discover that the arguments he uses for the general case are not valid for $k=1$. So, how to do it? How to obtain functions $(x_1, y_1)$ such that $\{ d_p x_1, d_p y_1  \}$ are linearly independent and $\{ x_1, y_1 \}= -1 $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a proof of your lemmas, but should answer the question in your last paragraph.

**Claim.** Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and take $p\in M$.  There are functions $x,y$ defined on a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ with $\{x,y\}=-1$.

(Proof.) Take a coordinate neighborhood $(U;u_1,\ldots,u_{2n})$ of $p$ and set $y=u_1$.  Now $\omega$, being nondegenerate, induces an isomorphism $T^*M\to TM$ which produces for each 1-form $\alpha$ a vector field $X_\alpha$ so that $\iota_{X_\alpha}\omega=\alpha$.  Applying this isomorphism to $dy$ gives us a vector field $X_y$ for which
\begin{equation}
\iota_{X_y}\omega=dy.
\end{equation}
Now let $x\colon U\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $\partial_x=-X_y$.  Then
\begin{equation}
\{x,y\} = \omega(X_x,X_y) = dx(X_y) = dx\left(-\partial_x\right) = -1,
\end{equation}
as desired.

I'd also recommend reading a proof of Darboux's theorem using the Moser technique.